# Proof for algorithm of Jordan normal form using cyclic basis

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Suppose $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ with
\begin{align}
\big|A-\lambda I_n\big|\,&=\,\pm(\lambda-\lambda_1)^{m_1}\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_p)^{m_p}
\newline
minpoly_A(\lambda)\,&=\,(\lambda-\lambda_1)^{n_1}\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_p)^{n_p}
\end{align}
admits the Jordan normal form
\begin{align}
J_A\,=\,\widetilde J_{m_1}(\lambda_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus \widetilde J_{m_p}(\lambda_p)
\end{align}
where $\widetilde J_{m_i}(\lambda_i)$ is Jordan matrix of order $m_i$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_i,\ 1\leq i\leq p$.

Let $\dim E(\lambda_i)=r_i$. By Jordan Theorem, we get
\begin{align}
\widetilde J_{m_i}(\lambda_i)\,=\,J^1(\lambda_i)\oplus\cdots\oplus J^{r_i}(\lambda_i)
\end{align}
where $\ J^{k_i}(\lambda_i),\ 1\leq k_i\leq r_i$ is the Jordan block corresponding to $\lambda_i$.

So we have
\begin{align}
J_A\,=\,\Big[J^1(\lambda_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus J^{r_1}(\lambda_1)\Big]\oplus\cdots\oplus\Big[J^1(\lambda_p)\oplus\cdots\oplus J^{r_p}(\lambda_p)\Big]
\end{align}
Suppose the block $J^{k_1}(\lambda_i)$ is of order $d_{ik_i}$. Let this matrix
\begin{align}
P\,=\,\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
P_{11} & \cdots & P_{1r_1} 
\end{pmatrix}
& \cdots & \begin{pmatrix}
P_{p1} & \cdots & P_{pr_p} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
P_{ik_i}\,=\,\begin{bmatrix}
\big(A-\lambda_iI_n\big)^{d_{ik_i}-1}u_{ik_i}^\top & \cdots & \big(A-\lambda_iI_n\big)u_{ik_i}^\top & u_{ik_i}^\top
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
with some vector $\ u_{ik_i}\in\ker\big(A-\lambda_i I_n\big)^{n_i}\setminus\ker\big(A-\lambda_i I_n\big)^{n_i-1}\ $ such that all these vectors are linearly independent.

Then, I want to show that
\begin{align}
P^{-1}AP\,=\,J_A.
\end{align}

I have no clue how to prove it. I hope someone will blow my mind with some interesting guidances. Thank you.